# Is it possible to develop multiple Whatsapp bots with one phonenumber?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

Whatsapp just released their api (yeah FINALLY!)
You have to confirm a phonenumber. I was wondering if you could create multiple Whatsapp bots with one phonenumber. Or you would need to buy prepaid cards for each new bot to receive sms and confirm that number.

Answer (score 1):

Each bot should have it's own number.
When a user sends a message, the correct bot needs to load which is not possible, as it cannot guess which one was intended.

A possible workaround is to combine all bots into a single one and create a redirection phase (first one obviously) with a "bot selection menu".
For example:

> Hi, please choose the correct service:
>
> 1. shopping helper
> 2. calendar
> 3. timer
> 4. app downloader

Choosing an option will load the requested agent